# How to improve this mergesort in scheme?

Tags: algorithm, scheme, mergesort

I am a C++ programmer, I wrote this code to see if I can think functionally :)
Any hints to improve it ?

```
(define (append listOne listTwo)
  (cond
    ((null? listOne) listTwo)
    (else (cons (car listOne) (append (cdr listOne) listTwo)))))

(define (merge listOne listTwo)
  (cond
    ((null? listOne) listTwo)
    ((null? listTwo) listOne)
    ((< (car listOne) (car listTwo))
     (append (cons (car listOne) '())
             (merge (cdr listOne) listTwo)))
    ((= (car listOne) (car listTwo))
     (append (cons (car listOne) '())
             (merge (cdr listOne) listTwo)))
    (else (append (cons (car listTwo) '())
                  (merge listOne (cdr listTwo))))))

(define (mergesort lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) '())
    ((null? (cdr lis)) lis)
    (else (merge (cons (car lis) '())
                 (mergesort (cdr lis))))))

(mergesort '(99 77 88 66 44 55 33 11 22 0))
```

Comment: It looks pretty standard to me  :)  Here is another version: https://ironscheme.svn.codeplex.com/svn/IronScheme/IronScheme.Console/build/sorting.ss

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll take a look at IronScheme :)

Comment: I took the liberty to format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one small improvement that I see:

```
(append (cons (car listTwo) '())
              (merge listOne (cdr listTwo))))
```

can everywhere be simplified to

```
(cons (car listTwo)
      (merge listOne (cdr listTwo)))
```

I think you were thinking of something like (in Python-esque syntax):

```
[car(listTwo)] + merge(listOne, cdr(listTwo))
```

But cons adds an item directly to the front of a list, like a functional `push`, so it's like the following code:

```
push(car(listTwo), merge(listOne, cdr(listTwo)))
```

Ultimately the extra append only results in double cons cell allocation for each item, so it's not a big deal.

Also, I think you might get better performance if you made `mergesort` fancier so that it maintains the list length and sorts both halves of the list at each step. This is probably not appropriate for a learning example like this, though.

Something like:

```
(define (mergesort l)
  (let sort-loop ((l l) (len (length l)))
    (cond
      ((null? l) '())
      ((null? (cdr l)) l)
      (else (merge (sort-loop (take (/ len 2) l) (/ len 2)))
                   (sort-loop (drop (/ len 2) l) (/ len 2)))))))))
(define (take n l)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (car l) (take (sub1 n) (cdr l)))))
(define (drop n l)
  (if (= n 0)
      l
      (drop (sub1 n) (cdr l))))
```

Comment: Doesn't the length function need to traverse the whole list? This can be quite expensive as it must be done for each recursive call to mergesort. I would define the split function without using length. It gets a bit more complex but it should be more efficient. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: `mergesort` is not recursive. `sort-loop` is. That's exactly why I call `length` once at the beginning of `mergeosrt`.

Comment: OK, I am learning Scheme so I did not read the code correctly. I thought length is called each time sort-loop is invoked. Instead, is it called once and bound to the variable ``len``? What happens to variable l in ``sort-loop ((l l) (len (length l)))``? Is a new variable l bound to the outer l?

Comment: Yes, and in subsequent iterations, other things are bound to the inner `l`, like the result of `(take (/ len 2) l)`, for example. Let-loops are syntactic sugar for `(letrec ((sort-loop (lambda (l len) ...))) (sort-loop l (length l)))`. That's the way you would write the loop in Caml, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `mergesort` is doing a lot of list manipulations, so it is much better to do things destructively by sorting sub parts "in-place".  You can see the [implementation of `sort` in PLT Scheme](http://svn.plt-scheme.org/plt/trunk/collects/scheme/private/sort.ss) for example of a common code, which originated in SLIB.  (It might look intimidating on first sight, but if you read the comments and ignore the knobs and the optimizations, you'll see it all there.)

Also, you should look at [SRFI-32](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-32/) for an extended discussion of a sorting interface.

Comment: The first link you have posted seems to have gone. Do you know if there is a new location for _implementation of sort in PLT Scheme_?

Comment: @Giorgio: We've switched to git since then, which is [where you can find this file now](http://git.racket-lang.org/plt/blob/HEAD:/collects/racket/private/sort.rkt); but we also switched the implementation of `sort` to something different.  See the code for references.